# Remove duplicates in array separated by double commas in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array in **JavaScript** like this

```
var data = [,A_1_VII,VII,V2,,A_1_VII,VII,V2,,A_1_VII,VII,V2,,B_1_XIV,XIV,V3,,B_2_XVI,XVI,V3]
```

when I alert in JavaScript it gives as below

,A_1_VII,VII,V2

,A_1_VII,VII,V2

,A_1_VII,VII,V2

,B_1_XIV,XIV,V3

,B_2_XVI,XVI,V3

But I want like this which is duplicates removed array

```
var unique_data = [,A_1_VII,VII,V2,,B_1_XIV,XIV,V3,,B_2_XVI,XVI,V3]
```

On **alert** it should give like this 

,A_1_VII,VII,V2

,B_1_XIV,XIV,V3

,B_2_XVI,XVI,V3

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also your current JS example will throw an error.

Comment: That is a really strange javascript array. Is this code valid javascript?

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst it is, if those are valid variables.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I doubt that variable names can start with a comma.

Comment: @BojanIvanac it works for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAWPT.png

Comment: Actually I am storing in that format in array so I can able to send this data to front end side easily. And this is how I am pushing into array,  data.push(["",my_data.id,my_data.class,my_data.name]);

Comment: Already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array?page=1&tab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: You can't check for duplicates by variables names, only by values.

Comment: @BojanIvanac: No, but arrays can have empty entries in them, which is what that array has. (This is as of ES2015+) For example: `[,,,1,,,]` is perfectly valid (in ES2015+).

Comment: @Bheru Lal Lohar  already I tried that. Its not working

Comment: @bioinform Are the values you want to stay unique always in groups of 3?

Comment: why not using an array of objects ? It would be way easier like `data.push(my_data)` resulting in `[{ id: 'value', class: 'value', name: 'value' }]`

Comment: @BojanIvanac in groups of 3 considered as 1 item in my array.

Comment: @bioinform and the groups are always separated by a double comma right?

Comment: check that alert thing which I included. For every three items internally separated by a comma but when  it comes one item to another, one more comma is there which separates group of three into one item.

Comment: @bioinform check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Thing your array contains string as a constant that's not going to work.

Secondly, if all of you value are strings you can do it as follows:

```js
var data =[,"A_1_VII","VII","V2",,"A_1_VII","VII","V2",,"A_1_VII","VII","V2",,"B_1_XIV","XIV","V3",,"B_2_XVI","XVI","V3"];

var uniqueArray = data.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return data.indexOf(item) == pos;
})

alert(uniqueArray);
```

Comment: Not working man. I tried this already. Now also again I tried. But not working.

Comment: @bioinform did you put all your values into double quotes, as above codes are working fine click on "Run code snippet"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the variables in your array are well defined, you can clean it up and remove duplicates with a `for` loop:

```
var data [/* ... */];
var unique_data = [];

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] && unique_data.indexOf(data[i]) === -1) {
        unique_data.push(data[i]);
    } 
}
```

Please note that the code above assumes that your array contains non-object types, otherwise the solution would need to use something more sophisticated than `indexOf()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your unique function to remove duplicate entry and empty value from array like this.

```js
var data =[,"A_1_VII,VII","V2,,A_1_VII","VII","V2",,"A_1_VII","VII","V2",,"B_1_XIV,XIV","V3",,"B_2_XVI,XVI,V3"]   
var unique_data = uniqueList(data);
alert(unique_data);
function uniqueList(list) {
  var uniqueResult = [];
  $.each(list, function(i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e, uniqueResult) == -1 &&$.inArray(e, uniqueResult)!="")// chech for unique value and empty value
      uniqueResult.push(e);
  });
  return uniqueResult ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```